# Sorting foreach results

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting

I have a foreach loop, where I want to sort the result by the distance.

```
foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) {

            $latitudeFrom = 123;
            $longitudeFrom = 123;

            $theta = $longitudeFrom - $this->item->longitude;
            $dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($this->item->latitude)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($this->item->latitude)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
            $dist = acos($dist);
            $dist = rad2deg($dist);
            $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
            $distance = $miles * 1.609344;
}

echo $distance;
```

I want to sort it by `$distance`. How can this be done?

Comment: I think you can just put everything in the body of the loop in a callback to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php  Your float will need to be converted to int representation, but that shouldnt be to hard.

Comment: @AlexBarker i cant get it from there. once i echo $distance i want it to be sorted.

Comment: What do you want, the array sorted by $distance, or just the farthest/shortest $distance?  Your example currently describes distance as a float.  I guess what I am asking is what is your desired "result."

Comment: @AlexBarker Yes i want an array sorted by $distance from nearest to farthest

Answer (score 1):

```
$latitudeFrom = 123;
$longitudeFrom = 123;

usort($this->items, function ($item1, $item2) use ($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom) {
    $distance1 = acos(rad2deg(sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($item1->latitude)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($item1->latitude)) * cos(deg2rad($longitudeFrom - $item1->longitude)))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344;

    $distance2 = acos(rad2deg(sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($item2->latitude)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($item2->latitude)) * cos(deg2rad($longitudeFrom - $item2->longitude)))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344;

    $result = 0;
    if ($distance1 < $distance2) {
        $result = -1;
    } else if ($distance1 > $distance2) {
        $result = 1;
    }

    return $result;
});
```

`$this->items` is now sorted.  To reverse the order, just switch the `<` and `>`.

Comment: Why not use spaceship operator here?

Comment: Although he/she should be using PHP 7 at this point, I know better than to assume that.  For those that are, `return $distance1 <=> $distance2;` should work.

Comment: There are no other versions available. You can't assume someone might still be using PHP 4, just write the code always as for the latest version unless question says otherwise.

Comment: REHL still supports PHP < 7. IIRC, they support something like PHP 5.3 or 5.4 in EL 7.  Furthermore, many, many shops still use PHP 5.6.  Someones always going to complain one way or the other.

Comment: Officially nothing less than PHP 7.1 is supported. If you as the answerer never upgrade, then what example do you give others?

Comment: Sure officially by Zend... and RedHat officially supports 5.4.  ::shrugs::